# Is there a relevance for where you place %include directive in NASM code?

Tags: assembly, nasm

I find that my assembly program executes differently when %include "filename.asm" is placed at different positions. I could not find any explanation to this anywhere. Can anyone shed light on this?

Answer (score 1):

For NASM, the `%include` is replaced by the contents of the file being included; and therefore there's lots of different ways for the location of the `%include` to effect the generated code.

For a simple example, imagine you've got a file called "myfile.asm" that contains this:

```
foo:    db 0
```

Now imagine a file like this:

```
    section .text
;%include "myfile.asm"
    section .data
;%include "myfile.asm"
    section .bss
;%include "myfile.asm"
```

In this case, where the `%include` is effects which section `foo` and its data is placed in; and if the last `%include` is uncommented you'd get an error (trying to put initialised data in an uninitialised data section).

Comment: so If I have a file which contains functions it would be best if i can place the include directive at a line where the control wont go normally. Is that right?